# SQL QUERY, GROUP FUNCTION

Tags: sql

I get this error

> ERROR- not a single-group group function

When I run the following query

```
SELECT STUDENT_NAME, MAX(VALUE) AS MAX_MARK 
FROM MARK JOIN STUDENT USING(STUDENT_ID)
ORDER BY STUDENT_NAME;
```

What am I doing wrong? Where does the problem lie?

Comment: Please specify your table architecture and more description to the question. Please work on the question harder than you want SO peers to work on the answer

Comment: `GROUP BY` is missing

Answer (score 0):

firstly you need to specify your question clearly, but I think you find something below

```
SELECT STUDENT_NAME, MAX(VALUE) AS MAX_MARK FROM MARK inner JOIN STUDENT
on MARK.STUDENT_ID = STUDENT.STUDENT_ID
  group by STUDENT_NAME
  ORDER BY STUDENT_NAME
```